# identify NULL and update for same key column in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a test table having below details:

```
ID  Key_COLUMN  final_Value
1   aaa          1234
2   bbb          2345
3   bbb          NULL
4   ccc          456
5   ccc          145
```

Desired Output:
--final_value updated from NULL to 2345 based key_column (bbb)

```
ID  Key_COLUMN  final_Value
1   aaa          1234
2   bbb          2345
3   bbb          2345  
4   ccc          456
5   ccc          145
```

Identify KEY column having NULL and value and update NULL with the value.

this update requied on huge amount of data

Please assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(final_value, max(final_value) over (partition by key_column)) as imputed_final_value
from t;
```

If you wanted an `update` -- to actually change the data -- you can use a correlated subquery:

```
update t
    set final_value = (select t2.final_value
                       from t t2 
                       where t2.key_column = t.key_column and
                             t2.final_value is not null and
                             rownum = 1
                      )
    where final_value is null;
```

Comment: Thank you! its working for me..Any ways to verify the records updated correctly in one go.. We have 1 million rows on table